# Plot a Density graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to draw a plot like
 [image]

where in this graph value of 1 is displayed by a white dot and a value of 0 by a black dot.   It should display the resulting value of the norm given `x` and `y` coordinates as inputs. That is graph similar to the article in [here](http://diuf.unifr.ch/is/studentprojects/pdf/reports/fuzzy_logic_SS04_Zadeh_and_Einstein_Operators_on_Fuzzy_Sets_(HannesGassert).pdf)

How can I draw this kind of a graph in Matlab? Does it done by using `Density` as described in  [here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/densitydata.html).
But I don't understand how the graph is drawn? If it is the **Matlab** command can someone please explain what are the arguments to it?
How can I draw this type of **density** graph ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several related ways to display what you're asking.  here are a few:

```
%define the value of r over a 2D grid:
x_vec = linspace(0,1,600);
[x,y] = meshgrid(x_vec,x_vec);
r = (x.^2 + y.^2).^(1/2);
%pixel coordinates begin at top left instead of bottom left, so flip the matrix:
r = flipud(r);
imshow(r);
```

If you'd rather the coloring **not** fill the grid, but be specified at **arbitrary** points, this will work:

```
N = 3000;
xvals = rand(1,400);
yvals = rand(1,400);
rvals = (xvals.^2 + yvals.^2).^(1/2);
size  = 30;
h = scatter(xvals,yvals,size,rvals,'filled');
colormap gray
```

Comment: `imshow(r)` plot for each x,y in the region of 0,600 right? But what I want is say x=[x1,x2,..,x25], y=[y1,y2,..,y25]. Then I want to plot pixels **only** for(x1,y1), (x2,y2),(x3,y3) only. Not **all** the x,y region points. That is I don't want points to be drawn for(x1,y3) likewise. How can I do this

Comment: Ok - so you want to specify the points first.  Do you want to color (arb.) pixels on a grid, or lay down points with *any* designated coordinates?

Comment: And please update your question, because you don't specify this!

Comment: What do you mean by `color (arb.) pixels on a grid` ?  What I want is for specified X and Y coordinates to display its density. All of these x and y values `x=[x1,x2,..,x25], y=[y1,y2,..,y25]` lie within the range `(0,1)`. So I want to display `1` by black pixel, `0` by white and the in between values by a shaded color like grey according to its density as it is being displayed on those graphs in my post. But the pixel colouring should appear for only the points such as `(x1,y1), (x2,y2),(x3,y3) ` **only**

Comment: Do you want all of your points to be on some underlying regular grid (like pixels) or randomly scattered x,y values

Comment: x,y values are random values